# What is the correct answer1?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> If
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}[\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(y)}]=a$$
>
> $$\lim_{y\rightarrow0}[\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(y)}]=b$$
>
> Then the values of $a$  and $b$ are
>
> (a) No such $a$ and $b$ exists.
>
> (b)$a=0$ but no such $b$ exists.
>
> (c)$b=0$ but no such $a$ exists.
>
> (d)$a=0 $ and $b=0$

$$a=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}[\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}]\implies a=\frac{1+\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=1$$ $\tag{By L'Hopital's rule}$

Similarly,$b=1$

Comment: d) is true of course!

Comment: De l'Hôpital? Are you sure you applied it correcly?

Comment: Just calculate it without L'Hospital.

Comment: You miscalculated the derivative of the numerator.

Comment: @Gibbs:I forgot to make the constant term zero while differentiating the numerator...

Comment: @PKStyles good that you spotted your mistake. Still, when you solve these kind of limits, I suggest you try to use techniques like the one gimusi applied in the solution below. This helps you using the right tricks instead of applying a powerful result like the theorem of de l'Hôpital.

Comment: @Gibbs:I'll take care of it next time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left[\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x+\sin y}\right]=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{\sin x}=0$$

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\left[\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x+\sin y}\right]=\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{0}{\sin y}=0$$